# powershell - split-path on string

Tags: powershell, split

I have a variable called $path which has a value of

```
My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2022-11-13 10-57-52.mov
```

trying to use split-path to get just **2022-11-13 10-57-52.mov**

```
Split-Path -Path $path -Leaf -Resolve               
Split-Path : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Tony\My Pictures\Tony\Automatic Upload\Tony’s iPhone\2022-11-13 10-57-52.mov' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Split-Path -Path $path -Leaf -Resolve
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Tony\M...13 10-57-52.mov:String) [Split-Path], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SplitPathCommand
```

don't have it working yet... any guidance ?

Comment: Your path contains an apostrophe, so define it using double-quotes: `$path = "C:\Users\Tony\My Pictures\Tony\Automatic Upload\Tony’s iPhone\2022-11-13 10-57-52.mov"`, OR double-up the apostrophe in the path `Tony''s iPhone`. Next, the switch `-Resolve` forces PowerShell to check if that path actually exists. If not it will throw an exception.

Comment: You can also use .Net: `[System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($path)`

Comment: Right-click on your movie file to find out the true path - it is probably not `C:\Users\Tony\My Pictures\Tony\Automatic Upload\Tony’s iPhone\2022-11-13 10-57-52.mov`, which is what PowerShell is looking for (since you don't define the full path in your variable).

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh Then better do `($path -split '[\\/]')[-1]` in case not all slashes are forward slashes

Comment: It works for me.  Note that that quote is "U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK".  Having any single quote in a folder name can be awkward, at least for tab completion.

Comment: Or you can do `($path -split("\\/"))[-1]`

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh  you really should not use operator `-split` with syntax as if it were a method (`.Split()`), so remove the round brackets and separate the operator from the parameter with a space character. `($path -split("\\/"))[-1]` --> `($path -split "\\|/")[-1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the split in the following way:

```
$path = "My Pictures/Tony/Automatic Upload/Tony’s iPhone/2022-11-13 10-57-52.mov"
$file = $path.Split("/")[-1]
Write-Output $file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care whether the file exists, you should use:

```
Split-Path -Leaf $path
```

If you ARE expecting the file to exist, then your problem is with the value in your `$path` variable.

*My Pictures* is a special folder, and the real path is not what you see in the Windows UI.
You can see the real path with the following command, for example:

```
[Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyPictures')
```

Or right-click on the file to get its properties and view the real path there.